# get custom gauge metric from WebMonitorEndpoint (Rest Monitoring API) in Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I've got custom metric ->

```
public class TestMetric implements Gauge<MyType> {


@Override
public MyType getValue() {
    final MyType myObject = new MyType();

    return myObject;
   }
}
```

And I'm using them as suggested in the documentation ->

```
getRuntimeContext().getMetricGroup().gauge("MyCustomMetric", new TestMetric());
```

I want to get this metric with GET method, but so far I tried almost everything in the API documentation (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/monitoring/rest_api.html ) but didn't find that metric.
Do you know how (or even could I) get that custom metric via API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to query the metric via Flink's REST interface you need to first figure some ids out:

- `flink_cluster`: Address of your flink cluster
- `port`: Port of REST endpoint
- `jobId`: Id of your job which can be figured out via `http://flink_cluster:port/jobs`
- `vertexId`: Id of the vertex to query. This can be figured out via `http://flink_cluster:port/jobs/:jobId` which gives you the job information with all `vertexIds`
- `subtaskindex`: Index of the parallel subtask to query

`http://flink_cluster:port/jobs/:jobId/vertices/:vertexId/subtasks/:subtaskindex/metrics?get=MyCustomMetric`

Comment: I just fond why I wasn't able to get it -> somehow we don't have a name of the operator, so the name of my metric was Co-Process.MyCustomMetric. When I changed it to this, it worked. Thank you.